# Many Django applications on same server

Tags: python, django

currently I'm running my Django websites using uWSGI on a server with Virtualmin because I need DNS, mail, etc servers too... So every time I need to publish a Django website I gotta create an INI file for this application, write nginx rules and finally restart my uWSGI emperor.....

So I was wondering if someone know any other way to do this easier and faster.

Thanks

Comment: You do not need to reload the Emperor when you add (or remove) a new config files. This will break half of the funny things it can does. Geneally you start the Emperor on boot and it is never touched again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/). These will allow you to do everything you mentioned and a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a single application per Django project, I typically do something like

```
www.mysite.com/app1
www.mysite.com/app2
www.mysite.com/app3
```

or use subdomains

```
www.mysite.com -> main application
app2.mysite.com
app3.mysite.com
```

This is also assuming that you have a virtualenv setup and have the folder `site` containing your source code, and your application files are within `site/app`.

Its easy to create a VirtualHost in your Apache server configuration's `sites-enabled` folder containing in part

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com

    Alias /static/ /path/to/virtualenv/site/app/static/

    <Directory /path/to/virtualenv/site/app/static>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/virtualenv/site/ >
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/virtualenv/site/django.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess  mysite.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=2
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com

     ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/mysite.com.error.log
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You do need to have a Python WSGI script at the path specified by `WSGIScriptAlias` as well as Apache `mod_wsgi` loaded.

Personally, I find it easier to configure subdomains than the first group of URLs I listed.